# Find two linearly independent solutions of the auxillary equation: $\frac{dx}{y+\alpha z} = \frac{dy}{z+\beta x} = \frac{dz}{x+\gamma y}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I recently encountered a question while studying Lagrange's Auxillary equations:

> Find two linearly independent solutions of the auxillary equation:
> $$\frac{dx}{y+\alpha z} = \frac{dy}{z+\beta x} = \frac{dz}{x+\gamma y}$$

The problem that I am facing is the presence of 3 different constants in the question. I have tried adding numerators and denominators to get equations in just 2 variables (so that it can be integrated to obtain a solution), but I could not get anywhere.

Would someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the PDE as:

$$\frac{adx}{a(y+\alpha z)} = \frac{bdy}{b(z+\beta x)} = \frac{cdz}{c(x+\gamma y)}=\lambda \space $$

where $\lambda$ is an infitesimal. Thus,

$$\lambda=\frac{adx+bdy+cdz}{a(y+\alpha z)+b(z+\beta x)+c(x+\gamma y)} =\frac{adx+bdy+cdz}{\rho(ax+by+cz)}$$
where $\rho$ is a real.

Thus, we have the following set of equations:

$$\rho a=\beta b+c , \space \rho b=\gamma c+a ,\space \rho c=\alpha a+b$$

For a solution to exist,
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}-\rho &\beta &1\\ 1&-\rho &\gamma \\ \alpha &1&-\rho \end{pmatrix}=0$$

$=> \rho ^3-\left(\alpha +\beta +\gamma \right)\rho ^2+1+\alpha \beta \gamma =0\space$ ( let the roots be $\rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_3$ )

Now, if $\rho=\rho_i\space$, let the solution be $(a,b,c)=(a_i,b_i,c_i)$, so

$$ \lambda =\frac{1}{\rho_i}\left(\frac{a_idx+b_idy+c_idz}{a_ix+b_iy+c_iz}\right)=\frac{1}{\rho_i }d\left(\ln\left(a_ix+b_iy+c_iz\right)\right) --(I)$$

Let $\space W_i=\frac{1}{\rho_i}ln\left(a_ix+b_iy+c_iz\right) for \space i=1,2,3$ , so integrating the equation $(I)$ for $i=1,2,3\space$ gives

$$W_1=W_2+\ln{\epsilon_2}=W_3+\ln{\epsilon_3}$$
where $\epsilon_2$ and $\epsilon_3$ are arbitrary constants.

> $$(a_1x+b_1y+c_1z)^{1/\rho_1}=\epsilon_2(a_2x+b_2y+c_2z)^{1/\rho_2} --(1)$$
> $$(a_1x+b_1y+c_1z)^{1/\rho_1}=\epsilon_3(a_3x+b_3y+c_3z)^{1/\rho_3} --(2)$$

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the required linearly independent solutions.